# Execute script on Azure Windows VM via Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I am using third party software for master data management. This software does not have API's to perform deployment across environment. It has command line utility which needs to be installed on machine and call the commands to perform the installation. I am looking to automate this solution using Azure Devops pipeline. What I am trying to do is as below

1. Create windows VM in Azure and install command line utility on it.
2. Store script in some folder in the VM.
3. Use Azure pipeline to call this script which is stored in my VM.

I don't even know if it possible to do such things. I tried looking on internet on how to call script stored in VM via Azure pipeline but didn't find any useful link.
If any one has done such activity or have an idea how can it be achieved please help.

Answer (score 0):

this can help you

Running the command line in a Azure Virtual Machine is fully supported in Azure Pipelines. You could install a self-hosted agent in the VM.

Before that, I recommend that you could create a new agent pool for the self-hosted agents. Please go to the organization settings -> Agent pools-> click the "Add pool" -> choose the "self-hosted" type.

Then, you could refer to this document to complete the installation. When you configure the agent, you could choose the new created agent pool.

After installation, you could create a pipeline, choose the new created agent pool and add a Command Line task to run the command line. Of course, if you have many agents in the same agent pool, you could also set the demands in the pipeline to specify one agent.

reference : [Is it possible to run a command line in a Azure Virtual Machine from Azure DevOps pipeline?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/is-it-possible-to-run-a-command-line-in-a-azure-vi/1075164)

Comment: Hi Mohammed, Thank you I tried it worked.. I have one more additional query. This script required zip file as input. The idea is that same zip file will be check in into Azure Repo and pipeline should download it on the Self host agent VM and then to call the script. I tried CopyFileTask but it is not working. Is there any other to copy the file from Azure Repo to VM?

Comment: Hi saagarlearn, if  CopyFileTask  not work you can try this [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) maybe that help you

Comment: Hi Mohammed,I already have windows machine reqistered as a agent. So need to copy to the same windows agent. Do I still have to use copy files over SSH?